# How to set the breakpoint when acessing the memory area(write) on the Keil ARM MDK

Tags: breakpoints, keil

The hardfault exception sometime occurs during the system is running.
Because the LR in the stack area is overwitten by a garbage data.

So I want to set the breakpoint when the LR in the stack is written by a specific data,
that is when any particular data is written to a particular address in memory.
(when the 0x12345678 is written to the address 0x20004321)

How can I do this on the keil's ARM MDK ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Breakpoints Window](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4cl/uv4cl_db_dbg_breakpnts.htm) with Expression: * ((uint32_t*)0x20004321) == 0x12345678 with Access: **Write**

You can also write to the **Command** window : BS WRITE * ((uint32_t*)0x20004321) == 0x12345678